# Testing after_save hooks in Rails 4.2 with MiniTest

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails, unit-testing

I've recently started working on a new application in Rails 4.2.0-beta2. I've been using this as an opportunity to learn more about MiniTest, with a stretch goal of being as strict with myself with testing as possible.

My general problem: How do I test the `after_save` action for an ActiveRecord model in such a way that I can be confident that an ActiveRecord callback will not cause my code to break?

Here's what I've got so far ([gist](https://gist.github.com/damien/af43487dbb4b9d57e69a) or inline code below).

How would you (re)write these files to detect if the `NotificationMailer` called in the `after_save` hook prevented a `TeamMembership` from being persisted?

Note that not included here are the relevant test fixtures. You may safely assume that fixtures `users(:carol)` and `teams(:alpha)` are not associated with each other.

**app/models/team_membership.rb**

```
class TeamMembership < ActiveRecord::Base
  # A proc that will enqueue `NotificationMailer.team_invitation`
  DEFAULT_NOTIFIER = proc do |user, team|
    NotificationMailer.team_invitation(team, user).deliver_later
  end

  class << self
    # This is a class level attribute that is mainly used for testing.
    # Defaults to {TeamMembership::DEFAULT_NOTIFIER}
    attr_accessor :notifier
  end
  self.notifier = DEFAULT_NOTIFIER

  belongs_to :team
  belongs_to :user

  after_create :invite_user_to_team!

  private

  # ActiveRecord callback used to equeue team invitation emails
  # @return void
  def invite_user_to_team!
    self.class.notifier.call(team, user)
    nil
  end
end
```

**tests/models/team_membership_test.rb**

```
require 'test_helper'

class TeamMemberTest < ActiveSupport::TestCase
  test 'callbacks' do
    # setup
    test_notifier = Minitest::Mock.new
    test_notifier.expect(:call, nil, [teams(:alpha), users(:carol)])
    TeamMembership.notifier = test_notifier

    # test
    TeamMembership.create(user_id: users(:carol).id, team_id: teams(:alpha).id)
    assert test_notifier.verify

    # teardown
    TeamMembership.notifier = TeamMembership::DEFAULT_NOTIFIER
  end
end
```

Comment: Not sure I understand. `after_create` is called, well, _after_ the record's been persisted. So a failure in the notification mailer shouldn't affect it.

Comment: If you were to create the model directly, then yes, that is the case. Unfortunately if I were to do something like `User.first.teams << Team.first` and that `after_create` action raised an error, the `TeamMembership` record does not seem to get persisted.

Comment: Really? Hmm... I'll have to check that out when I have the time. (until then: I think you can just say `test_notifier.verify` without the assert)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A valid approach would be check if `NotificationMailer.team_invitation` was called. In order to get this job done, you'll need first of all change this `NotificationMailer.team_invitation` hard-coded call to something injected. Something like this:

```
class TeamMembership < ActiveRecord::Base
  # other methods

  after_create :invite_user_to_team!

  def notification_method(notification_service = NotificationMailer)
    @notification = notification_service
  end

  private
  def invite_user_to_team!
    @notification.team_invitation(team, user)
    nil
  end
end
```

Now, you can create an **expectation** over `NotificationMailer`. Inside your test, you can define your mock and define its behavior:

```
class TeamMemberTest < ActiveSupport::TestCase
  def test_after_create_new_team_member_it_should_be_notified
    notification = Minitest::Mock.new
    notification.expects(:team_invitation).with(team, user).once
    # your TeamMember class working to create new
  end
end
```

I hope it helps :)

Comment: This is exactly the kind of feedback I was hoping for, thanks! I particularly like the way you default to the production use-case as a default method argument. This seems much cleaner and reads much more simply than the lambda constant I was using in my question.